# Discord.Net where to place SetGameAsync()

Tags: vb.net, discord.net

```
Imports Discord
Imports Discord.WebSocket
Imports Discord.Net.Providers.WS4Net
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Threading
Imports Discord.Commands

Public Module Main

    Private config As MasterConfig
    Private Client As DiscordSocketClient
    Private d_events As DiscordEvents
    Private commandHandle As CommandHandler

    Sub Main(args As String())

        RunBotASync.GetAwaiter.GetResult()

    End Sub

    Private Async Function RunBotASync() As Task
        Console.WriteLine("Now Loading Bot...")

        config = Await MasterConfig.LoadAsync

        Dim ClientConfig As New DiscordSocketConfig With {
                        .DefaultRetryMode = Discord.RetryMode.AlwaysRetry,
                        .LogLevel = LogSeverity.Info,
                        .WebSocketProvider = WS4NetProvider.Instance
                        }

        Client = New DiscordSocketClient(ClientConfig)
        d_events = New DiscordEvents(Client)
        commandHandle = New CommandHandler(config, Client)


        Await Client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, config.token)
        Await Client.StartAsync()



        Await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite)
        Await Client.SetGameAsync("Giving Damage While Taking Damage | -help", ActivityType.Playing, ActivityProperties.None).ConfigureAwait(False)
    End Function

End Module
```

So this is my whole function to get my bot running and connected. The issue I'm having is that I'm not entirely sure where to place `Await Client.SetGameAsync()` in the code. I've tried it above `Await Client.StartAsync()` and I don't get any errors but the status doesn't show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the Discord API Server, I figured it out. create a function with your custom status.

```
Private Async Function Ready() As Task
        Await Client.SetGameAsync("Others hit me while I take their health | -help", type:=ActivityType.Watching)
    End Function
```

and right below `StartAsync()` do `AddHandler Client.Ready, AddressOf Ready`
and now you have your custom status.